# Prove $(M^e \pmod n)^d \pmod n = M^{ed} \pmod n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Is $(M^e \pmod n)^d \pmod n = M^{ed} \pmod n$ ?

If this is true, how can I prove that?

Comment: Yes, it is true.  It is a consequence of the fact that 
$$
(M_1 \bmod n) (M_2 \bmod n)\cdots (M_k \bmod n) = (M_1M_2 \cdots M_k) \bmod n.
$$

Comment: thank you very much